# Change Fragments Only If They Go Through With The Intent (They Acually Share The App In This Case)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent, onclick

I have this code in MainActivity.java

```
FloatingActionButton fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab2);

fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                // "mailto","info@jmremovals.com.au", null));
            //tartActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));



            CompletedFrag compFrag = new CompletedFrag();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, compFrag);
            transaction.commit();



        }
    });
```

Now right now it brings up Share app screen and changes fragments but if i decide not to share the app i still change fragments.

So my question is can i do the same process as above but if they cancel without sharing the app (via the options provided) then it returns to the previous fragment i thought maybe a if else statement but i am new to android and don't know how it would do that!

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, i have found there is no solution (that i know of) that can do what i asked about, as it is handled by the android system itself and that stuff is lock tight. 
If you are trying to stop someone from accessing a page unless something is done, then i suggest you see if what you are looking for can be done via a website or similar.

I ended up abandoning this path and going a different path as even if i was able to stop changing fragments if they don't share to another person, they could just share to themselves and continue anyway.

Hope this may help someone.